# Why Python gensim package gives better coherence scores compared to TexmineR in R

Tags: python, r, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

I am really confused to see the results on the coherence scores using Python Gensim and R TexmineR packages.

I've trained both models for the same number of topics (from 5 to 15). Using the first one the average score is around 4.0, for the second one is not more than 2.0. So, for me the models coming from R are not to use as their coherence score is too low.

I would like to use R as I am more experienced in this language. But if I don't find a solution I will have to switch to Python.

Just wanted to know if you have any idea on how to solve this problem? Is it because gensim Python provide better quality algorithm?

Ps. I've tried training LDA in R with different parameters to make sure the source of the problem is not situated inthere.

Thank you in advance for your support and help.

All the best,
Evangelia